# usar ViewPager para incrementar variavel

Tags: android

bom o que eu queria era que meu ViewPager incrementasse uma variável dentro da Activity em que ele foi executado.
isso é possível?
só acho documentação para diferentes layouts

minha aplicação tem 1 página que eu simulo outras, para não carregar muito e por precisar de 60 páginas, eu criei um único layout, que quando o usuário manda mudar de página eu incremento uma variável global que altera todos meus textviews e os textos dos botões de acordo com as informações contidas no banco de dados. entao queria usar esse ViewPager para incrementar essa variavel e assim "mudar a pagina"

Comment: Acredito que se refira ao [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html), certo? Você tem algo para implementar nele como várias páginas ou simplesmente quer incrementar essa variável?

Comment: assim, minha aplicação tem 1 página que eu simulo outras, 
para não carregar muito e por precisar de 60 páginas,
eu criei um único layout, que quando o usuário manda mudar de página eu incremento uma variável global que altera todos meus textviews e os textos dos botões de acordo com as informações contidas no banco de dados. 

entao queria usar esse ViewPager para incrementar essa variavel e assim "mudar a pagina"

Comment: @Joannis, coloca essa informação em sua pergunta, para deixar mais claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pois bem, o que fiz bem rápido aqui, foi totalmente baseado no [exemplo](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) que indiquei pra você no comentário. Então, para simplificar sugiro seguir o inicio do exemplo em que ele monta o `ViewPager`.

Feito isso, como você terá apenas um `Fragment` mas com dados diferentes, na classe **ScreenSlidePageFragment** acrescente um parâmetro e o construtor passando o número da página:

```
private int position;

public ScreenSlidePageFragment(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}
```

Nesta mesma classe, no `onCreateView` você já tem o número da página e faz o que precisa ser feito, utilizando o banco de dados e etc.

Voltando agora no **ScreenSlidePagerAdapter**, você precisa passar o número da página no seu novo construtor, fica assim agora o seu *adapter*:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ScreenSlidePageFragment(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

Se quiser pode fazer o [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1o0NIBAU7UjNlVjTGZrNkZsTUU/view?usp=sharing) deste projeto que fiz e testar você mesmo (ignore o nome do projeto).

Comment: cara vlw.. 
entao minha duvida agora que tenho um 
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
e vc criou um 
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` estende `FragmentActivity`, então você pode usar o primeiro sem problema. Usei o `FragmentActivity` porque era o que estava no exemplo.